Trying to identify a 80s kids film: siblings in a big house, ghost of a teenage girl
As a kid in the 80s, I remember watching a film about siblings who go to stay/live in a big house. I’m not sure if they’re haunted by the ghost of a teenage girl or they befriend her?
I think there are some bad guys as I remember towards the end of the film, they’re getting away via a secret tunnel and find a large hole where the body of the girl laid undiscovered (it shows a clip of her falling in and unable to climb out).
At first I thought it was The Amazing Mr Blunden (1972), but it’s definitely not.

I suspect this may be the 1978 Disney TV Film Child of Glass based on your description.

Alexander Armsworth and his family move into an antebellum Louisiana plantation. Alexander's mother and sister become set on restoring the home to its former glory, but Alexander is unsettled by the mysterious lights he sees around the property. He also meets his new neighbor, Blossom Culp, a superstitious girl raised by her spiritualist aunt. In spite of Blossom's strange and sometimes annoying ways, she becomes a loyal friend.
One night Alexander sees the mysterious lights once more and follows them into the old barn, where he finds the ghost of a young Creole girl, Inez Dumaine, and her dog. Inez's uncle was the notorious pirate Jacques Dumaine, former owner of the plantation. In life, Inez was unable to reveal the location of her family's fortune to Jacques. In revenge he murdered her by throwing her down the well in the barn and cursed her ghost to remain on the property. In order to be free of the curse, Inez must solve a riddle and begs Alexander to help her, while warning him that if the riddle is not solved before All Saints' Eve (Halloween), she will be trapped on the plantation forever unable to reunite with her parents in the afterlife.
…
Meanwhile, Alexander's mother fires a disgruntled handyman, Amory Timmons, who burns down the barn as revenge. Alexander witnesses the fire and Amory attempts to kill him. Alexander escapes by running into the burning barn, but falls into the old well. Roused by the barn fire, Alexander's family realize that he is missing, while Amory has escaped. As the police search for Alexander and Amory, Inez's dog leads Blossom to the well house, where she sees the unconscious Alexander on a ledge. Blossom is the only one light enough to be lowered down the well to tie a rope to Alexander. While doing so, she discovers Babette on the same ledge. Both Alexander and the doll are taken safely from the well.

I had encountered this in a prior search (although it looks like I didn't submit it as an answer) and found it again with search terms of disney film girl ghost well
Alexander meets Inez




In retrospect, it's a well, not a tunnel, and there's just one villain, but I figure it's close enough to meniton.

+1 It is where my mind went!

“Welease me from my pwison or I will hunt you for the west of your days!” She sounds serious!

Thwo hew to the fwoow, @Giacomo1968!
